# How to set a breakpoint on all throws?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, breakpoints

Is there any way how we can specify a breakpoint to stop on all 'throw' statements? (symbolic breakpoint)

```
guard let id = UInt(idString),
      let changeset = UInt(changesetString),
      let uid = UInt(uidString)
else {
      throw OSMVectorMapDescriptionError.ElementAttributeConversionError(element: xmlNode, attributeº: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found an alternative in Xcode 8.3: there is a "Swift Error Breakpoint" option in the menu for adding new ad-hoc breakpoints:

[image: swift error breakpoint]

If you right-click the newly created breakpoint, you can even specify a particular `Error`-conforming type to break on.

[image: custom type]

Answer (score 24):

First thing to keep in mind is that errors thrown in Swift are not exceptions, just errors (`NSError`, whatever based on `ErrorType`, ...).

Second thing is, don't use `try!` unless you're damn sure it will not crash or if crash is what you really want.

Don't mix [symbolic breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html) with [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html). Different beasts.

Back to your question ...

`throw` is not a symbol, thus symbolic breakpoint doesn't work for you. But there's a way ...

```
(lldb)br s -E swift

-E <language> ( --language-exception <language> )
  Set the breakpoint on exceptions thrown by the specified language
  (without options, on throw but not catch.)
```

... this is little bit misleading, because thrown errors are not exceptions. Keep this in mind. When you try to set exception breakpoint in Xcode, there's no Swift. Probably the main reason is that thrown errors are not exceptions and they didn't figure out where to put it yet (who knows).

[image: Exception breakpoint - Edit]

**Add it manually**

Set a breakpoint somewhere in your code, when execution pauses, just type `br s -E swift` in LLDB prompt and then continue.

**Add it automatically**

Set a breakpoint somewhere in your code in this way ...

[image: Breakpoint br s -E swift]

... and toggle it (on/off) when you do want to stop on `throw`.

**Symbolic breakpoint**

When you do use already mentioned `br s -E swift` you are going to find that there's symbol for `throw`. Actually it's not `throw`, but `swift_willThrow`. Feel free to set symbolic breakpoint in this way ...

[image: swift_willThrow symbolic breakpoint]

... I do not recommend this way for now, because it can be changed in the future. But if it's enough for now, why not.

You can share your breakpoint across Xcode projects like this ...

[image]

... secondary click, *Move Breakpoint To*, *User*. Breakpoint will be visible in all Xcode projects.

When you hit breakpoint, you'll end up in something like this ...

[image: Breakpoint hit on swift_willThrow]

... and you have to select previous stack frame to see where the error was thrown ...

[image: Throw stack frame]

Comment: Just _What's new in LLDB_ session to get _br s -E swift_. Everything else is common breakpoints usage. Read LLDB or Xcode guides. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov you're right. Was working, but it doesn't work now. Anyway, I removed it from my answer and added an example how to share breakpoint across all Xcode projects (user based). No need to use `~/.lldbinit`.

Comment: Simply using a symbolic breakpoint for the Symbol `swift_willThrow` seems to be sufficient in Xcode 7.0 beta 5. Thanks!

Comment: thank you @robertvojta for the explanation! do you know how I can print the error that will be thrown when the debugger pauses for `swift_willThrow`?