# Remove Realm Model Object from Xcode

Tags: xcode, realm

Ages ago, I used Realm with iOS projects, but am no longer doing so. However, I still have the template available in Xcode as seen here:

[image]

It was never an issue until the Xcode 11 beta, where every time I run a project, I get the following in my console:

> error: module importing failed: invalid token (rlm_lldb.py, line 37)
>   File "temp.py", line 1, in

At this point, I'd just like to remove it, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do it from Realm.

Comment: See my very updated answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Xcode keeps its custom templates at:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
```

Folders are “groups” within Xcode.

If you navigate to that folder, (ensuring Xcode is not running) you can simple drag the Realm folder to the trash.

There may be files located at the following paths as well that can be removed (with Xcode *closed*)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py

~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmPlugin.xcplugin
```

Then I had to clean and run once - which crashed. But then I cleaned and ran a second time which worked, and has been working for a couple of weeks with no side effects.

Later I finally found the root cause which is still related to the plug in. There are two options;

1. If you want to continue to use the plug in which it installs the Realm Object template that can be used when creating new objects as well as add support for inspecting the property values of persisted RLMObjects in the debugger pane. Download the newest updated project from

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa

which has a folder called plugin with information for installing the plug in. I've installed it and that seems to correct the error outlined in the question which is related to [this error](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/6290)

2. Otherwise, if you want to remove the plug in entirely, the old template installer modifies a hidden file located at

   ~/.lldbinit

you can see it by going to the command line, navigating to your home folder

```
cd..
```

and then showing hidden files

```
ls -a
```

> The .lldbinit in your home directory is sourced in BEFORE the target
> you are going to debug is created. It's purpose is to set up the
> environment for creating that target.

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743326/lldbinit-doesnt-work-in-xcode).

So that file will contain this line

```
command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow-reload
```

which will try to set up your Xcode environment with the rlm_lldb.py file.

If you're not using the plug in and have removed the other files per above, you can further remove references to it by editing the ~/.lldbinit file.

If you are familiar with the pico editor you can edit the file with

```
pico .lldb
```

and either comment the line with a `#` or just delete the line entirely.

Credit goes to the answer by sahm to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090655/removed-realm-but-still-getting-this-error-module-importing-failed-invalid-to/59094519?noredirect=1#comment104464997_59094519).

Comment: @CodeBender I have that folder on my Mac and when removed, it removes that template from XCode. Putting it back adds it back in so that's definitely where it is in XCode 10. Maybe it's location is different for 11?

Comment: I had initially looked in the wrong folder. Your path was correct & did remove the template, thanks!

Comment: Did this actually fix that error for you? After removing the template I'm still getting it.

Comment: @DanMessing Yes, it fixed the error. When you start up XCode 11, is the template showing in the Realm section when adding a file to your project as shown in the screenshot in the question or are you seeing something different.

Comment: @Jay The template is gone, but the error is still showing up. I think the difference must be that I *am* using Realm in my project, so something else must be triggering the same thing.

Comment: @DanMessing Are you sure it's the exact same error? Did you try to clean your project and rebuild?

Comment: Yep, definitely the exact same error, and I've done all the cleaning and removing derived data folders and everything else I can think of to reset things. No luck so far!

Comment: @DanMessing By any chance is this a old project? Have you tried creating a new user and then opening the project? If it works, then you've modified XCode at some point in the past on your user account and whatever was modified is throwing that error. If you've ever installed [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) that may also be involved as it's Realm related..

Comment: @DanMessing do you resolve this issue. I have same problem after upgrade xcode 11

Comment: @Jay Good idea about trying a new user account! My suspicion is that it's caused by including the realm framework.

Comment: @symbool I haven't, but I also haven't noticed any bad side effects in my app, so I'm not sure how worried I should be about it.

Comment: @DanMessing thanks. I comment out the code starting at line 37. file in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py. 
In fact, you can ignore this problem

Comment: Commenting out al one in a file I didn't create makes me a bit nervous...

Comment: @DanMessing I agree with your. Commenting out code should NOT be a fix. Did you try it with a new user account and see if the error goes away. I am not able to duplicate that issue so perhaps there is more to your situation - as I mentioned above SwiftLint could be causing an issue if it was ever added.

Comment: @DanMessing Please see the updated answer with a LOT more info.

Comment: @Jay That did it! Thank you so much for following up with this!

Comment: Well, that was annoying! Commented out the .libinit and that fixed the issue. So annoying. I really hate hidden files. Especially when there are no comments so you have no idea if they are important or not.

Answer (score 7):

The rest of the Realm plugin can be disabled by editing `~/.lldbinit` and removing or commenting out this line:

```
command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow-reload
```

Add a `#` to comment it out:

```
#command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow-reload
```