# Removed Realm, but still getting this error: module importing failed: invalid token (rlm_lldb.py, line 37) File "temp.py", line 1,

Tags: python, ios, realm, cocoapods

I tried using Realm with Cocoapods in a project two years ago. Realm didn't work out, so I removed it. Cocoapods didn't work out, so I eventually removed that as well and switched to Carthage.

With the advent of Xcode 11, I started seeing this error:

```
error: module importing failed: invalid token (rlm_lldb.py, line 37) File "temp.py", line 1, in <module>
```

It didn't seem to cause any crashes, so I stupidly ignored it. Last night I ran an app on an iPod Touch Generation 6 running the latest iOS 12 (12.4.3). The app crashed with this error.

I realized then that I was getting this error for every app on every device, including the simulator.

I tried going back and re-ran all of the code to remove CocoaPods, and it seems like it is really removed.

There are still some Realm files on my computer, most notably:

```
~Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py

~Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RealmPlugin.xcplugin
```

When I delete those files (by renaming and moving them), I still get an error every time I run any app on any device:

```
error: module importing failed: invalid pathname
```

Something is still looking for those files, but it doesn't even know their name. So I put the files back, and I am back to the original error.

EDIT:
It was suggested that this is the same issue as:
[Remove Realm Model Object from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385022/remove-realm-model-object-from-xcode)

I do not have the Realm Object Model in my Xcode, even though I am getting the same error. The solution to that question did not address my situation at all. There is another comment that may be helpful to this issue, and that is to edit `~/.lldbinit`. But there is no explanation of how to edit `~/.lldbinit` or suggestion that it worked at all.

I actually think that editing `~/.lldbinit` might help, but I have no idea how that might be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Realm Model Object from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385022/remove-realm-model-object-from-xcode)

Comment: I did see that question. I do not have the Template showing nor do I have the Templates directory.

Comment: I can see that I may need to edit lldbinit, but answer from that question did not address how to do that. Answer is unrelated to my question.

Comment: I may be getting the same error, but the Realm Model Object is not in my Xcode.

Comment: @Jay any guidance on how to solve this particular issue?

Comment: I believe it's directly related as the old installer both adds files and I believe modifies the XCode app package as well. I have found the fix that worked for me is to delete the actual XCode app and then re-download it as well as deleting the mentioned files.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that.

Comment: Just deleted and reinstalled Xcode. Same exact issue.

Comment: The answer is that I have to edit that file directly. I have literally no idea how to do this without blowing up my machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode did not solve this issue for me.

As per the unaccepted answer in this question,

[Remove Realm Model Object from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385022/remove-realm-model-object-from-xcode)

I needed to edit `~/.lldbinit`. To be honest, I don't completely understand what this file is. It is not easy to get to or to edit.

I found this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich,

https://www.raywenderlich.com/612-custom-lldb-commands-in-practice

found my way to the editor, highlighted the offending line,

```
command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow$
```

removed the text, and exited, choosing to save upon exit.

When I re-opened Xcode, cleaned, built and ran an app, the error was gone.

I don't feel great about this. I don't know if I did the right thing. I hate doing things in the Terminal that I don't understand.

EDIT:
I raised this issue to Realm, who had also suggested around the same time that the issue might be with `lldbinit`. After I edited the file and stopped seeing the error, I shared the steps I took to fix the problem with Realm. It was confirmed to me that that was the right thing to do. Additionally, please see the comment from Jay below about how he was able to solve this issue:

> For future readers, interestingly enough, I was able to duplicate this
>   issue but the solution was different. I was able to delete the files
>   showin in the original question, then clean and run the project. THEN,
>   clean and rebuild again and it seems to be working. Both files appear
>   to be circa 2016.

While this did not work for me, I want to include it in this answer because I think it would be good to try this first if you are having this issue.

Comment: For future readers, interestingly enough, I was able to duplicate this issue but the solution was different. I was able to delete the files showin in the original question, then clean and run the project. THEN, clean and rebuild again and it seems to be working. Both files appear to be circa 2016.

Comment: I'm so glad that worked for you, and I'm glad you are sharing it was well. If this works for someone, then it is definitely preferable to editing the lldbinit file.

Comment: Super great answer and it lead me to a lot more info. I updated my answer in [Remove Realm Model Object from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385022/remove-realm-model-object-from-xcode). I have installed the latest version of the plug in because it adds support for inspecting the realm objects persisted property values in the debugger, and seems to correct the error.