# Handling errors in swift with try/catch

Tags: swift, exception, swift2

I come from a .NET background, where error handling can be as simple as wrapping a set of statements in a try-catch. For example:

```
try
{
   statement1
   statement2
}
catch (ex)
{
   log(ex.Message)
}
```

I'm trying to add error handling in my Swift project, and all the articles I have read so far seem to indicate that error handling requires more work in Swift. In the example above, it seems I would need to know exactly which statement throws an error, and then add a "try" before it. Is it not possible to simply wrap a block of code in a try-catch, and inspect the error that gets thrown?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508

Comment: Wow, that seems like a lot of work. My app is crashing, and all I wanted to do is add a simple try/catch around the suspected code and do some logging, but it seems like I need to do a lot of exception design work before I can do that!

Comment: To inspect the error that gets thrown, set [an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31580070/1457385).

Comment: @shallowThought I'm in a situation where something works fine when running from XCode, but crashing when running on TestFlight. So, I can't add breakpoints...

Comment: Is it really that unreasonable to require devs to know what functions they're trying to catch errors from?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Sometimes, in service oriented architecture, there is so much dependency on 3rd party software, and we can't always design for all error possibilities up front--it's an incremental process. Having the ability to quickly detect an arbitrary exception can be a great boon for developers. C# does this really well. Swift chose not to give us this power, possibly for good reasons. But that doesn't mean that it's not a good feature to have in a programming language.

Comment: @Prabhu I've used C# for my previous work, but I don't see what "feature" you're talking about. You're not being forced to catch all exceptions in a Java-like checked exception design, you just need to declare which functions can throw, which is obvious, because the compiler will tell you if you forget

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't just wrap a block of code with try-catch.

First of all, cause not every line of code could produce exceptions. Only functions marked as "throws" could produce exceptions.

For example, you have some function:

```
deserialise(json: JSON) -> MyObjectType throws
```

And let this functions throws exceptions of type **MyErrorType**

That's how you should use it:

```
....
do {
  let deserialisedObject = try deserialise(jsonObject)
  ... // do whatever you want with deserialised object here
} catch let error as MyErrorType {
  ... // do whatever you want with error here
}
...
```

So, as you see, exceptions in swift is not the same thing as exceptions in C++(or other regular language) for .NET

Answer (score -1):

You can use try catch in swift just like you do in .net with this little change in structure,
before that create a enum of exceptions which you want to catch like follows

```
//exceptions to catch, change as per your need
enum someActionError: Error {
    case invalidSelection
    case outOfStock
}

//use
do {
    try statement1
} catch someActionError.invalidSelection {
    print("Invalid Selection.")
} catch someActionError.outOfStock {
    print("Out of Stock.")
}
```